# Transform a recursive function and make it iterative

Tags: c++, c, recursion, iteration

Basically I have a recursive function, that I don't want to be recursive anymore.
But I can't figure out the logic of the existing code itself.

Here it is

```
float myRecursiveFunction(x, y, depth, divisor) {
    if(depth == 0)
        return result(x/divisor, y/divisor);

    float displace = myRecursiveFunction(x, y, depth-1, divisor/2);

    return result(displace+(x/divisor), displace+(y/divisor));

}
```

and here is how it is called :

float myresult = myRecursiveFunction(x, y, 5, 2);

it will ALWAYS be called with 5 and 2.

Any of you have an idea on how to proceed ? or if it's short enough, a code with no recursion ?

float result(float, float) isn't important here, it is just a function that returns a random float. The point here is to remove the recursion

Comment: The core of the function is another function called `result`, which is not defined here.

Comment: That's not the issue, result() just returns a random float.

Comment: So your function is returning a random float. No iteration needed.

Comment: The point of this is to make a recursive function become iterative, no matter what result() does.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You don't need the definition of `return()` to determine what `myRecursiveFunction` could be implemented as an iterative function.

Comment: What result does is the key to making the function non recursive. The easiest form of recursion to eliminate is tail recursion and if this is possible depends entirely on what the code after the recursion does, so what result does underpins the whole question.

Comment: @Neva You could trace your function calls, displaying x, y, depth and divisor at the begining of your function. That would help.

Comment: As it is now this question does not meet "must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"

Comment: What are the types of `x`, `y`, `depth`, `divisor`?  Is `depth` an integer type?  Is `divisor` a floating point type?  Are `x` and `y` also `float`?

Comment: x, y and divisor are floats, depth is an integer.

Comment: This is no valid signature. Provide a proper prototype with argument-types. This might be important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
divisor *= (1/2.0) ** depth
r = result(x/divisor, y/divisor)
for i in range(depth -1):
  divisor *= 2
  r = result(r + x/divisor, r+y/divisor)

return r
```

Be careful, you might be losing precision if you do it this way.

Hope I didn't forget some -1/+1 somewhere.

Comment: `**` is not an operator in either C or C++.

Comment: Sorry, it think faster in python, but should be trivial to convert to C++.

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you.